# spring populating ServletActionContext?

Tags: spring, struts2

We use Spring IoC and Struts as the web app framework. There is a helper class in the presentation layer which reads some stuff from request and populates some data as request attributes for the action and other classes to use. So we need the request object (HttpServletRequest) in this class, and we use ServletActionContext.getRequest() for this.

The helper class is a Spring bean in request scope, and gets invoked for all requests. The data loading happens in a method which is configured as "init-method" in the helper's Spring bean. The actions are also Spring beans.

In struts.xml, we refer to the action beans configured in spring by name. For eg:

```
<action name="myAction" class="actionBeanNameFromSpring">
    <result>myResult.jsp</result>
</action>
```

In this case, the ServletActionContext.getRequest() method in the helper returns the proper request object. However, we have other actions in the XML where we directly refer to the action class instead of action bean i.e. we bypass Spring. In these cases, the request comes out as null.

Now I know that the solution to this is to change all action entries in XML to refer to Spring beans. But I would like to know why exactly this happens. AFAIK, ServletActionContext is a Struts thing and is handled completely by Struts. How does going through Spring (i.e. using Spring action beans) populate the context, and not going through Spring (i.e. using Action class name) doesn't?

@Roman

I am assuming the entire content is unnecessary. Given below is the relevant part:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    ....

    <!-- the helper which accesses request -->
    <bean id="myActionHelper" class="com.company.product.webapp.package.MyActionHelper" init-method="init" scope="request">
        <property name="someSvcBean" ref="someSvcBean" />
    </bean>

    ....

    <!-- a typical action -->
    <bean id="myAction" class="com.company.product.webapp.action.MyAction" scope="request">
    </bean>

    ....

</beans>
```

Comment: Post the applicationContext.xml.

Comment: @Roman : Done, please see original post

Comment: couldn't reproduce the solution, struts takes the request from the action context, which is created when filtered the request, and it's local to a thread in which it was created. Any other way to obtain the request object leads to `null`. If you got this value the spring can't much help with it's request object that it manages itself.